# how to build out gstreamer plugin: omxh265enc？

Tags: linux, gstreamer, cross-compiling, openmax

I’m trying to build and test gstreamer on my linux machine, I have build out gstreamer and most of the base/good/bad plugins successfully and all the plugins can be detected by gst-inspect-1.0. But I got a problem, that is, cannot find the plugin "omxh265enc".

It seems that the omxh265enc is supplied by gst-omx, and I build gst-omx with configure below, but cannot get plugin "omxh265enc" yet.

```
./configure --prefix=${PWD}/__install \
    --disable-gtk-doc  \
    --disable-gtk-doc-html \
    --disable-gtk-doc-pdf \
    --disable-examples \
    --with-omx-target=generic \
    --enable-experimental \
    --enable-omx
```

Some one can teach me how to building out plugin omxh265enc?

Comment: Which version of the package are you currently building, and is Meson available for the build process? Consider trying it with Meson.